# Problems with ArrayList, for loop and if statement - prints line for each item in the list

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, contains

I am a complete beginner when it comes to programming and was hoping to get some help. My program has an ArrayList (dogRegister) of dog objects with different attributes such as name and age, entered by the user.

The program is supposed to be able to update a dog's age and delete a dog from the list, among other things. The user is asked to enter the name of a dog to delete, and if the entered name is in the list, the dog will be deleted. If the name isn't included in the list, the program prints "Dog not found". Same goes for the age command, if the name is included, the dog will become 1 year older. If it isn't - "Dog not found".

I'm struggling with the if statement and its conditions. My code and strategy doesn't work, since it prints "not found" for every item on the list until it finds the correct one. I just want it to be printed once, and ONLY tell if the item is found or not. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Let me know if you need to see more of my code.

```
 public void deleteDog(){
    System.out.print("Enter name of dog to delete: ");
    String nameOfDogToDelete = readString(); //returns the nextLine();

    for (Dog dl : dogRegister) {
        if (dl.getName().contains(nameOfDogToDelete)) {
            dogRegister.remove(dl); 
            System.out.println("Dog deleted.");
        }
        else if (!dl.getName().contains(nameOfDogToDelete)) {
            System.out.println("Dog not found.");
        }
    }
}

public void editAge(){
    System.out.print("Enter name of aging dog: "); 
    String nameOfAgingDog = readString(); //returns the nextLine();

        for (Dog a : dogRegister) {
            if (a.getName().contains(nameOfAgingDog)) {
                a.updateAge(); //method returning the dog's age++
                System.out.println("Dog's age updated.");
            }
            else if (!a.getName().contains(nameOfAgingDog)) {
                System.out.println("Dog not found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Break out of the loop as soon as you delete the entry, so that further iterations are not checked.
2. If you do not want to print for the "not found" cases up till that point, don't include a print for the "not found" case. Check the whole list, and then if the entry is still not found, then print "not found". You can use a boolean variable to keep track of this.

You have made a check in the if condition, and you are again making a check in the else condition by passing the same check again. So when the name of the dog to delete is found, it deletes it, and proceed further to check in the other iterations  in the loop. So as soon as you find the dog to be deleted and you delete it, break out of the loop.

```
public void deleteDog(){
    System.out.print("Enter name of dog to delete: ");
    String nameOfDogToDelete = readString(); //returns the nextLine();
    boolean isFound = false; //To keep track of whether the dog is found or not
    for (Dog dl : dogRegister) {
        if (dl.getName().contains(nameOfDogToDelete)) {
            dogRegister.remove(dl); 
            System.out.println("Dog deleted.");
            isFound = true;
            break;//Break out of the loop as soon as you find it
        }
        // else //no need to check the negation of the above condition again
        //   System.out.println("Dog not found.");
        // }
    }
    if (!isFound)
         System.out.println("Dog not found.");
}
```

Comment: Patience, man.. easy on the downvote.. I was typing an explanation as you commented

Comment: I retracted my down vote, but this will still not work as expected by the OP, eg consider what happens if `nameOfDogToDelete` is not the first dog in the list...

Comment: Updated the explanation

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Latest update. Sorry, bad net speed here.

Comment: You might want to move that `if(!isFound)` out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, my code works now! :)

Comment: Patience, man.. don't FGITW. If your answer is incomplete, wait to complete it before posting it.

Comment: Noted @SotiriosDelimanolis :D :D Like I said, bad network, was going to update whole thing immediately. Thanks for making me aware of the acronym too :D :D

Comment: @Nathalie : You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

While looping just check for if the dog is found and mark the boolean field found as true. If not found , when the loop end , print not found

```
 public void deleteDog(){
    System.out.print("Enter name of dog to delete: ");
    String nameOfDogToDelete = readString(); //returns the nextLine();
    boolean found =false;

    for (Dog dl : dogRegister) {
        if (dl.getName().contains(nameOfDogToDelete)) {
            dogRegister.remove(dl); 
            System.out.println("Dog deleted.");
            found =true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
     System.out.println("Dog not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include some explanation outside of that code.

Comment: Added , you can always ask what you did not understand in the code .

Comment: I'm not the op, I understand your code fine, but code without explanation is usually not really helpful.

Comment: yes you are correct . Please check if the code works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, my code works now! :)